# Bitwise operators used in a particular context

Tags: python

The following function generates all possible combinations of N items:

```
def powerSet(items):

    N = len(items)
    # enumerate the 2**N possible combinations
    for i in range(2**N):
        combo = []
        for j in range(N):
            # test bit jth of integer i
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:  #  What's happening here?
                combo.append(items[j])
        yield combo
```

The line `if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:` uses bitwise operators.
I have read about bitwise operators, but I still do not understand how this line works.

Comment: The solution is to research bitwise operators, not ask an off topic question asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you already researched and what exactly are you confused about?

Answer (score 0):

For information about bitwise operators in Python you can have look at e.g.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

https://realpython.com/python-operators-expressions/#bitwise-operators

or read through the existing discussions about this topic here on Stack Overflow:

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bitwise+operators+python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bitwise%20operators%20python)

Comment: The most important part of being a developer is to learn how to find solutions on your own and educate yourself ;)